# Invoking a script, which has an awk shebang, with parameters (vars)

Tags: shell, awk, shebang

I have an awk script that I have defined thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk
BEGIN { if (!len) len = 1; end = start + len }
{ for (i = start; i < end; i++) { print $1 } }
```

I have saved it as `columns` and `chmod +x`'d it. I want invoke it so that `start` and `end` are defined as it traverses over a file. I was thinking this should work:

```
cat some_file | columns -v start=2
```

But it doesn't. Help!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try using:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

as an interpreter

Comment: +1 for the most portable solution, as it only uses a single argument. Even though the path to `awk` is hard-coded - of necessity, due to having to make do with _one_ argument - this should work on all modern Unix platforms. (Do tell if you know of any where it doesn't.)

Comment: @mklement0 It doesn't on mine (NixOS). Since NixOS keeps all packages isolated and on non standard paths. I think using mss's answer would be better in my case.
**EDIT** That doesn't work either since `-S` is non POSIX compliant :(

Comment: @PallavAgarwal: Good to know about how NixOS differs. Note that as long your OS can handle _multiple_ tokens on the shebang line, you're good; in other words: `#!/usr/bin/env awk -f` _may_ work for you (works on OS X, for instance, but not on Linux).

Comment: @mklement0 Had that worked, I would've never come across this question in the first place. And anyway the whole point of trying to find the right shebang was to make a script that works everywhere. If I had to, I could write #!/nix/store/<full path to awk executable> -f

Comment: @PallavAgarwal: Understood. We can conclude that there is no portable solution that works on all platforms (short of creating a wrapper executable).

Answer (score 16):

env is the easiest way to handle this problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f
```

to add more options, and to ensure no interference with your arguments, and awk's arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -F: -f ${_} --
BEGIN {
    # delete argv[1], which == ENVIRON[_]
    delete ARGV[1]
} # rest of my awk program
```

as env has a POSIX standard, this shbang should get you around the difficulties of non-standard shbang implementations across unixen.

*EDIT*

after having written this **I realized that '-S' is a non-POSIX compliant FreeBSD env extension**.  So shell wrapper is probably the way to go, unfortunate as that is.

Comment: We're looking to add this to GNU coreutils after version 8.29

Comment: Note that `${_}` relies on the `_` environment variable being [set by the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005f) from which you launched the script, and will not work if the script isn’t launched directly from a shell.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not easy to solve in a portable way. The standard technique looks like this (substitute `/usr/bin/awk` for your awk path):

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { if (!len) len = 1; end = start + len }
{ for (i = start; i < end; i++) { print $1 } }
```

The hard-coded `awk` path and non-standard `-f` flag, makes this not portable across all *nixes. If you are only ever going to run your script on one machine, then this may work fine. However, to make a portable `awk` script, you will need to wrap it in a shell script. Here are two ways that you can do it in one file:

The first way is standard and easy to read:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

awk '
BEGIN { if (!len) len = 1; end = start + len }
{ for (i = start; i < end; i++) { print $1 } }
' "$@"
```

Unfortunately, this falls short in two key ways:

1. If your awk script contains a `'` character, you will need to type it like this: `'"'"'` to "escape" it.
2. If you are using a text editor with syntax highlighting, you will not get your awk script properly highlighted.

Another solution, is to use `sed` to strip out the `sh` wrapper:

```awk
#!/bin/sh
exec awk "$(sed '1,2d' "$0")" "$@"

BEGIN { if (!len) len = 1; end = start + len }
{ for (i = start; i < end; i++) { print $1 } }
```

This is something like a two line shabang header. It calls awk using the file from line 3 down as the script argument. This allows you to keep your pretty syntax highlighting and you can still use `'` characters to your heart's content. The two downsides I see are:

1. Arguably this is non-intuitive to read.
2. If you are using a code linter, it may not like this.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer for this problem -

```
#!/bin/awk -f
```

Comment: While this work well for gawk, it has problems on debian/ubuntu as they use `mawk` on `/usr/bin/awk` that does not support `-f` option.

Comment: @OliverGondža in my system (Ubuntu 20.04) it works with mawk, too.