# "bad interpreter" error message when trying to run awk executable

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to make an awk file executable. I've written the script, and did `chmod +x filename`.  Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/awk -v

'TOPNUM = $1

## pick1 - pick one random number out of y
## main routine

BEGIN {
## set seed
        srand ()

## get a random number

        select = 1 +int(rand() * TOPNUM)

# print pick
        print select
}'
```

When I try and run the program and put in a variable for the `TOPNUM`:

```
pick1 50
```

I get the response:

```
-bash: /home/petersone/bin/pick1: /bin/awk: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I'm sure that there's something simple that I'm messing up, but I simply cannot figure out what it is. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `awk` really installed to `/bin/awk`?

Comment: try "which awk" to see where akw is or put #!/usr/bin/env awk at the top instead of #!/bin/awk. If which awk doesn't show anything you need to install awk.

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) for a discussion of the pros and cons of the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick. And note that you can't use `#!/usr/bin/env awk -v`; it doesn't take multiple arguments.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e) discusses how to pass a command-line argument to awk.  So does [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97141/distributing-a-script-should-i-use-bin-gawk-or-usr-bin-gawk-for-shebang).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a command line, run this command:

```
which awk
```

This will print the path of AWK, which is likely `/usr/bin/awk`.  Correct the first line and your script should work.

Also, your script shouldn't have the single-quote characters at the beginning and end.  You can run AWK from the command line and pass in a script as a quoted string, or you can write a script in a file and use the `#!/usr/bin/awk` first line, with the commands just in the file.

Also, the first line of your script isn't going to work right.  In AWK, setup code needs to be inside the `BEGIN` block, and `$1` is a reference to the first word in the input line.  You need to use `ARGV[1]` to refer to the first argument.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html

As @TrueY pointed out, there should be a `-f` on the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

This is discussed here: [Invoking a script, which has an awk shebang, with parameters (vars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418245/invoking-a-script-which-has-an-awk-shebang-with-parameters-vars)

Working, tested version of the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

## pick1 - pick one random number out of y
## main routine
BEGIN {
    TOPNUM = ARGV[1]

## set seed
        srand ()

## get a random number

        select = 1 +int(rand() * TOPNUM)

# print pick
        print select
}
```

Comment: With normal awk should be `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this form is more preferrable:

```
#! /bin/awk -E
```

Man told:

> -E Similar to -f, however, this is option is the last one processed and should be  used with #! scripts, particularly for CGI applications, to avoid passing in options or source code (!) on the command line from a URL. This option disables command-line variable assignments

Comment: This is a good point, but it doesn't answer the question. It should have been a comment. (But you need at least 50 rep points to post comments on others' posts.)