# Shebang multiple parameters

Tags: linux, shell, awk, shebang

I am currently writing a `awk`script which looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    print "Starting extracting data"
}
{
    print $0
}
END {
    print "End of file"
}
```

My script works fine like that on my computer but it is not portable... I'd like to do something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f
...
```

but the Debian shell does not accept several parameters in a single shebang. I get `"awk -f" no such file or directory`.  Is there any workaround I could use or is it completely impossible ?

Comment: Can you show the full command how you invoked the `awk`?

Comment: `awk`'s `f` option expects a program file which seems completely unnecessary in your example.

Comment: @Inian I do `./awk-script mylog.log`

Comment: @fd0 the `f` option always `awk` to read the following commands. If I don't put it, it does not work

Comment: @Xatyrian: you cannot run it like a shell script, the `-f` option tell `Awk` to parse a script rather to look for command line arguments. You definitely need to invoke `awk -f <script-name> <file>`

Comment: @Inian well, not according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418245/invoking-a-script-which-has-an-awk-shebang-with-parameters-vars) and the fact that it works well on my computer. Anyway, I think there is no portable solution still thank you for trying to help me :) !

Comment: @Xatyrian: If you carefully read through the comments in the accepted answer passing arguments in she-bang line is not supported in Linux, you can still use `#!/usr/bin/env awk` and pass `-f` while calling the script.

Comment: @Inian I didn't downvote your answer :o i was actually suprised you removed it. sorry this happened

Comment: @Xatyrian: Usual SO behavior, some people just look at a few comments and think my answer didn;t solve your problem and downvote away! Thanks

Comment: @Xatyrian I know it doesn't answer your question, but would a simple wrapper shell script (invoking awk with all the necessary arguments) be an acceptable solution? At least it's portable.

Comment: @RuudHelderman sure it will but i'd rather not use this solution

Comment: This is [documented in the `execve(2)` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/execve.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this cleanly; as mentioned in [glenn jackman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612626/shebang-multiple-parameters#comment78193711_45612626), shebangs are implemented by [`execve()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/execve.2.html), which only accepts an interpreter and a *single* optional argument.

You'll need a workaround.

The comments to the question imply you don't want a wrapper script, but what if it's contained inside the final ~awk script?

```sh
#!/bin/sh
awk -f - "$@" << 'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    print "Starting extracting data"
}
{
    print $0
}
END {
    print "End of file"
}
```

This uses portable POSIX shell in its shebang and then immediately invokes awk with awk code from a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) on standard input (`-f -`), passing the further arguments and options (`"$@"`) to awk as files.  The heredoc is quoted (`<< 'EOF'`) so things like `$0` aren't interpreted by the POSIX shell.  Since a line consisting solely of `EOF` is not present, the heredoc ends with the file.

(The second shebang is not read by anything.  It's purely cosmetic for people who read the code.  If you name this file with the `.awk` suffix, editors like `vim` will default their syntax highlighting to awk despite the contents of the first shebang.)

That code won't work for piping content into the file because the script is itself piped into awk.  If you want to support piping, it needs to be a little uglier, using bash's input [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (`<(…)`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec awk -f <(awk 'NR > 2' "$0") "$@"
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    print "Starting extracting data"
}
{
    print $0
}
END {
    print "End of file"
}
```

This tells bash to execute awk on a named pipe created from that second awk command, which reads the full script (bash interprets `$0` as the name of the file it is running) and prints lines 3 and higher.  Again, the second shebang is purely cosmetic and is therefore just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason to invoke awk in the shebang.  Just invoke it via sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec awk '
BEGIN {
    print "Starting extracting data"
}
{
    print $0
}
END {
    print "End of file"
}
' "$@"
```

Comment: This might (? I'm not sure) run into size limits due to being effectively a single command line.  That's why my answer used heredoc or process substitution.  There's a pretty good chance that the awk script is small enough that it doesn't matter, in which case this is probably the simplest solution.