# Local vs Supplied Shell Script Arguments

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Writing a shell script that receives 3 arguments but within the script one of the commands needs to check the first value after a delimiter is applied

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F'\t' '$1 ~ /$1/&&/$2/ {print $1FS$3}' $3
```

this command is called:

```
bash search.sh 5 AM filename.txt
```

And should execute as follows:

```
awk -F'\t' '$1 ~ /5/&&/AM/ {print $1FS$3}' filename.txt
```

The command functions properly outside of the shell script, returns nothing right now when using it inside the shell script.
filename.txt :

```
03:00:00 AM John-James Hayward  Evalyn Howell   Chyna Mercado
04:00:00 AM Chyna Mercado   Cleveland Hanna Katey Bean
05:00:00 AM Katey Bean  Billy Jones Evalyn Howell
06:00:00 AM Evalyn Howell   Saima Mcdermott Cleveland Hanna
07:00:00 AM Cleveland Hanna Abigale Rich    Billy Jones
```

Expected output:

```
05:00:00 AM Billy Jones
```

Comment: Is there a tab after `AM`? If not, the time and name will be one field.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Can your timestamps every be anything other than on the hour, e.g. could you have `03:05:20` in your input? Are you trying to print lines that occur at exactly that time or within the hour that starts with that first number?

Comment: How is midnight represented in your input - `00:00:00 AM` or something else?

Comment: There is a tab after AM. The timestamps could theoretically contain more than just the hour, for the purposes of this assignment they would not.  And yes, midnight is represented as 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arguments are not being expanded by the shell when you single quote them. You can use awk variables (as suggested by @JohnKugelman
) to more clearly separate shell and awk code:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F'\t' -v p="$1" -v p2="$2" '($0 ~ p && $0 ~ p2) {print $1FS$3}' "$3"
```

I use generic variable names here (`p` and `p2`) to emphasize that you are *not* anchoring your regex so they really do match on the hole line instead of hour and am/pm as intended.

Comment: It would be better to pass variables to awk with `-v` to avoid trouble with special characters.

Comment: @EdMorton you, sir, are a tease :-)

Comment: So -v p="$1" creates a temporary variable within the command, referenced using p and representing $1 as supplied to the shell script?  Meaning it would have to be included again if I were to have another line in the code that needed to reference it?  Also, $0 ~ p is checking the whole delimited section for p , correct?

Comment: Yes, it creates an awk variable called `p` with the value "$1" which the shell expands to the the first command line argument in this case.  You can reference `p` in your awk script as many times as you want.  Yes, the awk variable `$0` is the whole line, and `$0 ~ p` checks it against the regex `p`.  You set the field separator with -F, so you can use $1, $2 etc (it's not clear what is space and what is tab separated in your test data, or if you really want to match against specific fields; see the other answers for that).

Comment: Btw, you can also skip the shell entirely and just write an awk scripting using the she bang `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` but that might be gnu awk specific.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418245/invoking-a-script-which-has-an-awk-shebang-with-parameters-vars

Answer (score 0):

Don't embed shell variables in an awk script.

Here's a solution with some explanatory comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $# -lt 2 ]] && exit 1       ## two args required, plus files or piped/redirected input

hour="$(printf '%02d' "$1")"   ## add a leading zero if neccesary
pm=${2^^}                      ## capitalise

shift 2

time="^$hour:.* $pm\$"         ## match the whole time field

awk -F '\t' -v time="$time" \
'$1 ~ time {print $1,$3}' "$@" ## if it matches, print fields 1 and 3 (date, second name)
```

Usage is `bash search.bash HOUR PM [FILE] ...`, or `./search HOUR PM [FILE] ...` if you make it executable. For example `./search 5 am file.txt` or `./search 05 AM file.txt`.

I'm assuming that every field is delimited by tabs.

Comment: If every field is delimited by tabs then `time="^$hour:.* $pm\$"` with a blank instead of a tab between the first 2 fields can never match any input line. The `.*` is a bit fragile too in case `AM` or `PM` can occur mid-word further along the input line (bear in mind some names exist that may not conform to your expectations of which characters are used in what orders!).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're trying to do (untested, using any awk):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v hour="$1" -v ampm="$2" '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "\t"
        time = sprintf("%02d:00:00", hour)
    }
    ($1 == time) && ($2 == ampm) {
        print $1, $3
    }
' "${3:--}"
```

Note that the above would work even if your input file contained `10:00:00 AM` and the arguments used were `1 AM`. Some of the other solutions would fail given that as they're using a partial regexp comparison and so the arg `1` would match the `1`s in input of `10:00:00`, `11:00:00`, or `12:00:00`.